# How can I get numbered classes on rows?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I worked briefly with Drupal 7 and I thought it was possible there but in Drupal 8 is it possible to have a view output an increasing numbered CSS classes for Views rows?

This is what I want.

```
<div class="view">
  <div class="view-row-1"></div>
  <div class="view-row-2"></div>
  <div class="view-row-3"></div>
  <div class="view-row-4"></div>
</div>
```

I know I can add a CSS class to every row and give every row the same class.

Answer (score 11):

In Drupal 7 and 8 the add view row classes is check-marked by default.

[image]

**The problem is that in Drupal 8, it does not work. (looks like this is a bug)**

[image]

As you can see in the above picture, the number is missing on the div class.

## Luckily, there is a workaround solution.

In FIELDS, add Global: View result counter and hide it from display

In FORMAT, click on Settings (the 1st one)

For row class, put for example: `hello-{{ counter }}` and uncheck-mark "add view row class", as you don't need it.

[image]

### Result

[image]

Comment: For reference, it is this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2669394

Answer (score 5):

I liked the solution provided by **@No Sssweat**

As the above solution still an issue in https://www.drupal.org/node/2669394.

Other way is **Rewrite results** where you can add the classes like you need.

**Add Global: View result counter and hide it from display**

```
<div class="views-row-{{ counter }}">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use the module [Semantic Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews) to number row classes, first/last and every nth row, custom markup and more.

> This Views plugin makes unformatted styles, field row styles and other
> output more readily configurable without needing to override template
> files. Instead of overriding row style templates for views where you
> want to specify different HTML elements (tags) and class attributes,
> you can specify these inside the Views UI and avoid overriding
> templates for each view.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this in your views-view--[view name].html.twig template by replacing

```
{{ rows }}
```

with

```
{% set totalrows = rows[0]['#rows']|length %}
{% for row in rows[0]['#rows'] %}
     {% set rownum = ( rownum | default(0) ) + 1 %}
     <p>This is row: {{ rownum }} of {{ totalrows }}</p>
     {{ row }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by simply changing one line in the default views template.

Add a copy of `views-view-unformatted.html.twig` to your theme and change this:

```
set row_classes = [
  default_row_class ? 'views-row',
]
```

to this:

```
set row_classes = [
  default_row_class ? 'views-row views-row--' ~ loop.index,
]
```

As long as "Add views row classes" is checked in the Views UI, the div classes will show as follows:

```
<div class="views-row views-row--1"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row--2"></div>
<div class="views-row views-row--3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the easiest way to print numbered CSS classes in Views rows was per the following Twig snippet.

```
{% for key, row in rows %}
  <div class="view-row-{{ key+1 }}">
    {{ row }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This will output the following markup.

```
<div class="view-row-1"></div>
<div class="view-row-2"></div>
<div class="view-row-3"></div>
<div class="view-row-4"></div>
```