# How can I target the first item in a view?

Tags: views, theming

I have a views page that shows all the latest articles that were posted. I want to show case the latest article in a different div on it's own, and then have my loop with all the other articles.

This is my code for the loop, which is in the node--view.html.twig file -

```
    <div{{ attributes.addClass('col-4')}}>
      <div class="news-card">
        <img src="{{ file_url(node.field_image.entity.fileuri) }}">
        <h3>{{ node.label }}</h3>
        {% set text = content.body|render|striptags %}
        <p>{{ text|length > 100 ? text|slice(0, 120) ~ '...' : text }}</p>
        <a href="{{ url }}" class="btn black-btn">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and in my views-view-unformatted.html.twig file I have -

```
<h2>{{ view.getTitle() }}</h2>
  {% if title %}
      <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
  {% endif %}
<div class="row news-row">
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class,
    ]
  %}
    {{- row.content -}}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also do

**views-view-unformatted.html.twig**

<sub>**Note:** add the view name if you want to target a specific view, *views-view-unformatted--view-name.html.twig*</sub>

```
{% if title %}
  <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
    default_row_class ? 'views-row',
  ]
  %}
  {% if count == 1 %}
    {%  set row_classes = row_classes|merge(['first-row']) %}
  {%  endif %}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{- row.content -}}
  </div>
  {% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

and then in css

```
.first-row { ... }
```

---

OR alternatively follow [How can I get numbered classes on rows?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/191512/how-can-i-get-numbered-classes-on-rows/191514#191514)

and

```
.views-row-1 { ... }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. When someone's new here, i always assume Drupal newcomers as well (even when this could be totally wrong). So i try to give answers that are possible without touching any code... ;)

Comment: +1 for being a good sport @Volker

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution ist to create two views. One for your featured content (only 1 item or as much you want to feature) and the second one for the rest with an offset. You can set the offset under pager options (items to skip).

Comment: Can I display both views on one page?

Comment: Yes, just output them as blocks. Alternatively you can use an 'attachment' as display and attach it before or after a page display.

Comment: Do you know if I can edit the attachment on a different twig file? Before the attachment the debugger suggets - node--view--news--attachment-1.html.twig 

Right now my file is node--view.html.twig, and it's still loading that even if I create a node--view--news--attachment-1.html.twig  file. Do you know if I can have 2 files? 1 for the attachment, 1 for my other content?

Comment: @jfc You can definitely have separate twig files for each view display.  If it's not being picked up, double-check the file name, clear the cache, and so on.  The pattern is usually `views-view--VIEW_MACHINE_NAME--DISPLAY_MACHINE_NAME.html.twig`.

Comment: While this answer works, not the best, you're making things more complicated than it needs to be by having to manage two views.